Can AWS services replace SQL Server Agent Jobs?
I've decided that I no longer want to use SQL Server Agent Jobs. They're tightly coupled to SQL Server, cause interesting security/permissions problems, and can be complicated to sequence. I instead want to replace them with AWS services, under the assumption that they will be easier to move to Postgres should I ever switch away from SQL Server.
I currently use SQL Server Agent Jobs for the following tasks. Can they be done with AWS Services?

Running T-SQL code at regular intervals without any care for what it returns, e.g. updating a particular table once an hour.
Running T-SQL code at regular intervals and using its results to update CloudWatch metrics.
Running T-SQL code at regular intervals, exporting the result to CSV, then saving that CSV in an S3 bucket.
Running SQL Server Maintenance Plans.
Firing SSIS packages.



Can AWS services replace SQL Server Agent Jobs?

Sure, in the same sense that Walmart can replace McDonald's. Both sell food, but one of them requires you to cook the food yourself and it may not come out as tasty as the other. It's kind of comparing apples to oranges.
Taking a step back, AWS stands for Amazon Web Services, and is a whole suite of cloud situated services of all different kinds, that aren't necessarily related to each other. Just like Walmart sells all kinds of products, not necessarily just food. Some of those services encompass database systems themselves (e.g. DynamoDB and Athena), some of those are for file management (such as S3 Buckets and Glacier storage), other services allow ways write code to execute and schedule jobs for that code (e.g. Spark and Glue).

I currently use SQL Server Agent Jobs for the following tasks. Can they be done with AWS Services?

Running T-SQL code at regular intervals without any care for what it returns, e.g. updating a particular table once an hour.


Yes.


Running T-SQL code at regular intervals and using its results to update CloudWatch metrics.


Yes.


Running T-SQL code at regular intervals, exporting the result to CSV, then saving that CSV in an S3 bucket.


Yes.


Running SQL Server Maintenance Plans.
Firing SSIS packages.


Yes...
But it's all just the same as if you used C# or any programming language to write your own jobs. AWS just gives you a platform to host such processes, and / or create workflows and connect services together. But by being decoupled from SQL Server itself, it will require more work to accomplish the same goals as SQL Agent Jobs, if your goals are native SQL Server things. (Not commenting on if that's necessarily a bad thing for your use cases, just something to be mindful of.)
AWS is not a direct alternative to SQL Agent Jobs, just as much as Azure services aren't either.

FWIW, I find SQL Server Agent being one of the best out of the box job scheduling systems for its flexibility, automatic auditing, and its robustness. I personally prefer not having to codify my own management tools for things that already exist like this.

I've added a bounty. You may enjoy it.
